# Creating a news feed realtime

Tags: php, ajax, xmpp, real-time

I have a database containing many tables : [followers, favorites, posts ...etc)

These tables define the different activities a user can achieve, he can send posts, add other people to favorites and follow others.

What I want to do.. is to extract data from these tables, and build a real-time news feed .

I have two options:

1- Creating a separate table for the notifications (so that I won't have to get data from multiple tables, then using a Javascript timer to return results every x seconds.

2- using XMPP server...that sends (or pushes) notifications every x second, without actually sending any ajax queries.

And for these two options, I don't know whether I should connect to these tables to get news feed, or just create a separate table for notifications.

I searched in the subject, but I didn't find something really helpful yet, Any links will be appreciated.

Comment: You can also consider the use of a pub/sub mechanism that will push notifications in real-time.

Comment: I agree with MasterAM, think you could probably accomplish everything here with XMPP pubsub alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is [normalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), you should be able to pull all the data with one query (using JOINs), or you could try creating a [View](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) if you want to query from one table. It's always best to keep your data in the appropriate tables to avoid having to duplicate data.

The push notifications are easier on the server, since they're not receiving requests from each client. Depending on your load, you could probably get away with simple AJAX requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I will check your link on how to normalize data...I'll use the first option. +1

Answer (score 2):

The request for news feed will be very frequently. So you must keep your code run fast and take as less resource (`CPU-time`, `database query`) as possible.

I suggest you to take the first option. It meets your requirement and is simple enough.

Because you have many tables, all of them will `grow bigger day by day`. Every time you connect them to get news feed will take a long time and increase the load of your database. In the other hand, you query sql will be complex.

Like @Curtis Mattoon said: `avoid having to duplicate data`, but sometime, we need `spend more space for less time`.

So I suggest to create a new table to store the notification data. You even can delete the  old data from this table periodically.

At the same time, your sql and `php code` for news feed will be simple and run fast.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, I will use the first option, But for creating a table for notifications, I think like @curtis, it's better not to duplicate data. I will do more search about this part. and +1